# Ruby: Is it possible to set an if statement == to 2 variables?

Tags: ruby

I am making a simple program that censors a users input based on the words chosen.

```
puts "Enter your Text: "
text = gets.chomp.downcase!

puts "Word to censor: "
censor1 = gets.chomp
censor1.downcase!

puts "Second word to censor: "
censor2 = gets.chomp
censor2.downcase!

words = text.split(" ")
words.each do |letter|
  if letter == censor1
    print "CENSORED "
  else
    print words + " "
  end
end
```

So, is it possible to set: 'if letter == censor1 and censor 2' ?

Comment: The "and" doesn't make any sense. You probably meant "or".

Comment: I gave an answer that interpreted your question as others had, but now I'm not so sure, so I modified my answer.  You need to edit the question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if object present in array with the help of [`Array#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F)

```
if [censor1, censor2].include?(letter)
```

A bit simplified variant of your code:

```
puts 'Enter your Text: '
text = gets.chomp.downcase
puts 'Word to censor: '
censor1 = gets.chomp.downcase
puts 'Second word to censor: '
censor2 = gets.chomp.downcase

text.split(' ').each do |word|
  if [censor1, censor2].include?(word)
    print 'CENSORED '                                                                                                                                                                  
  else
    print word + ' '
  end
end
```

And much easier and better solution with [`String#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) which replaces all occurrences of censored words in text:

```
puts 'Enter your Text: '
text = gets.chomp.downcase 
puts 'Word to censor: '
censor1 = gets.chomp.downcase
puts 'Second word to censor: '
censor2 = gets.chomp.downcase

[censor1, censor2].each { |c| text.gsub!(c, 'CENSORED') }
puts text
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if either (downcased) `censorX` contains the character `letter`:

```
censor1+censor2.include?(letter)
```

If you are asking if both `censorX`'s contain the character `letter`:

```
censor1.include?(letter) && censor1.include?(letter)
```

If you are asking if all `censorX` strings equal the string `letter`, then:

```
if [censor1, censor2,...].uniq == [letter]
  ...
end
```

Comment: It seems the correct answer, though... I am still getting this error:  http://m.imgur.com/AZbQqjG

Comment: `,...` following `censor2` is there just to show it can be generalized to any number of `censorX`'s. Remove `,...` to run it for just the two. @JesseSielaff, did you mean your comment to be to the OP?